# QFileSystemWatcher not emitting fileChanged signal for changes done by another application

Tags: python, c++, qt, user-interface, tcl

I am trying to detect changes in files modified by another tcl/python application.
I used QFileSystemWatcher addPath for the files.
It does not emit fileChanged(QString) signal for changes in files.
However, when I manually edit these files, fileChanged signal gets emitted and slot is executed.

Answer (score 0):

Check that in your tcl\python program you actually flush the data to the file using f.close() \ f.flush() \ using the 'with' statement.

P.s.
Sometimes python waits until end of execution to actually write the data to the files. If this is what's happening here, the files won't be changed until the tcl\python program ends its execution and thus the signal won't be emitted until then aswell.

Comment: I checked tcl code. The file has a close $outPort. For python code, the file is created by moving tempFile like this:
runCmd = "mv -f %s %s" % (tmpFile, liveFile)

os.system(runCmd)

I want to watch 3 files. Its working for first file that is created by another python api. Other two files are not being detected. I tested by just adding two files that do not work but no luck.